# How to delete an object after 5 minutes? Celery

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

I am trying to create a periodic task with celery to delete an object after 24 hours of expiration, I have searched and tried several solutions but none of them work

celery.py

```
import os

from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'arhi.settings')

app = Celery('arhi')


BASE_REDIS_URL = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')
app.conf.broker_url = BASE_REDIS_URL


app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'every-1-minute':{
        'task':'tarea.tasks.delete_file',
        'schedule':60,
    }
}
app.conf.timezone = 'America/Bogota'

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

models.py

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


# Create your models here.

class Archivo(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    file = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    fecha_subida = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Archivos'
```

Celery executes any other task that you assign to it, but this one to delete some object does not execute it

tasks.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from celery import shared_task
from .models import Archivo

@shared_task
def delete_file():
    files = Archivo.objects.filter(fecha_subida__lte=timezone.now())
    if files:
        files.delete()
        return "files eliminados"
    return "no hay archivos"
```

Comment: Did you start the "beat" (with `celery -A proj beat`)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  yes

Comment: exaclty what do the celery logs show? Both that one of the beat, and the one that handles the messages?

Comment: it shows me the following when executing beat: https://ibb.co/2Ps9hkq

Comment: and the worker? Does the worker receives the "beat"?

Comment: i think so... https://ibb.co/fkxvSkX

Comment: you run these both at the same time, right? Otherwise it will only generate/consume beats. Not do this periodically. The logging indicates that the "heart" already has created a lot of beats before the worker actually performed the task.

Comment: if I run them at the same time, but before it only ran one :(. How can I solve this?

Comment: I got it to work! apparently the problem if was when running the workers and the celery. so restart my redis and use the following commands to run it: 
celery -A ahri.celery beat -l INFO
celery -A ahri.celery worker --pool=solo -l info 

Thak you! @WillemVanOnsem